# how to get li elements and add as select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sincerely speaking I'm using [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/), when I add values in it I get a ul like this

```
<ul id="mytags" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
<span class="tagit-label">Android</span>
<a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a>
</li>
<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
<span class="tagit-label">Java</span>
<a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a>
</li>
<li class="tagit-new"><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add those dynamically added `li` as `options` to a `select`. I have found an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JVS7d/)
as I've no any experience in JS world I have changed that to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/4/) but not getting results and that does not add `li` as options to select any help please.

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle ?

Comment: here's fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/ , the fiddle does not contain logic of adding li to options !!!

Answer (score 0):

U can try this

```
<select id="yourSelect"></select>

<script>
    var allItems = document.getElementById("mytags").children;
    var i = 0;
    var len = allItems.length;
    var element;

    for(; i<len; i++) {
        element = document.createElement("option");
        element.textContent = allItems[i].textContent.slice(1, -2);
        document.getElementById("yourSelect").appendChild(element)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nope this does not work please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LjomqhbL/14/